# Topic Challenge #01: the Review Spew

Tags: discussion, topic-challenges

> *“The time has come,” the Meta said,
>
>   “To speak of many things;
>
>   Of [Challenges](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207/topic-challenges), of brand new tags
>
>   Of S.E. shirts as bling.
>
>   And why some lesson didn’t work
>
>   And making worksheets zing.”*
>
> **- With Apologies to Lewis Carroll**

Indeed, the time has come!  Our first question challenge, in case you haven’t figured it out yet, is [???-review tagged](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187/introducing-the-new-tags-curriculum-review-lesson-review-and-materials-re) questions.  There are already two questions that exist that I created as models.

**Here are the rules for questions:**

1. The questions must be posted between **0:00, 7/14** and **23:59, 7/24** (UTC).  Any questions posted before the start of 7/14 or after 7/24 will not qualify.  Edits made between the close of the day on 7/24 and the final judging may disqualify the question.
2. The question must be tagged with [curriculum-review](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/curriculum-review), [lesson-review](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lesson-review), or [materials-review](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/materials-review) to be considered.
3. *Every question asked with the appropriate tag will automatically be entered.* However, after you post your question, there are two additional steps that would help the contest to stay organized. You should post this comment to your question: `*This question has been entered into [the -review question contest](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210/topic-challenge-01-the-review-spew).*`  You should also create an answer **right here in this very meta** with a link to your question.

**It is a little easier for an answer to get considered:**

1. Any top-voted or accepted answer posted to a properly entered question before the close of the contest will automatically be given consideration.  Edits made between the close of the day on 7/24 and the final judging may disqualify the answer.
2. That is all.

**Now, as for the judging criteria for** ***questions:***

1. 10 points per upvote on the question itself.
2. 2 points per answer that is created, and 2 points per upvote on any answer.  *So, if an answer is created that gets 3 upvotes, it will be worth 8 points to a question’s overall score).  Self-answers will not earn the question points, but may still gain upvote points in this category.
3. Each judge may award up to 25 points based on *how much of an exemplar the question is for the tag*, and up to 5 additional points for *any other considerations* (such as great writing, etc).

**Judging criteria for** ***answers:***

1. 10 points per upvote on the answer itself.
2. 15 points if the answer is accepted.
3. Each judge may assign up to 5 additional points each for:

   1. Whether the answer strictly answers the question.
   2. Whether the answer additionally teaches *how* to think about the problem as well.
   3. Any other considerations (such as quality of writing)

**When the winners have been announced, which will likely happen on 7/25/17, they will be announced here.  Those users will then be given private instructions about how to go about collecting their t-shirt!**

---

#### Note:

This event has been extended to end on 7/24 instead of 7/21.

Comment: About edits after the close. It's possible for anyone besides the OP to edit a post. If someone besides the OP edits the post, don't disqualify it, but judge it based on the version at the time of contest ending.

Comment: Definitely! It would be unfair otherwise.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you limited to one question per person for the entire competition, or can you post multiple questions?

Comment: You can definitely post multiple questions!! Highly encouraged, even. :)

Comment: @Michael0x2a Post _all_ the questions! The more you post the higher the chances that one will win! And you know you want that Stack Exchange t-shirt!

Comment: Sorry I have read this twice and don't get it. Is there a topic for the question? What?

Comment: @richard It's the first contest.  Create any [tag:lesson-review], [tag:materials-review], or [tag:curriculum-review] question, and you could win a t-shirt :)

Comment: All dates should be ISO 8601, I know the date is 2017-07-25, but only because there is not 25th month, and because it is soon after now (this last clue will not be there for historians, and the first clue is not there for dates at the beginning of the month).

Comment: @BenI. tags have no usage guidance, so it is hard to know.

Comment: https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187/introducing-the-new-tags-curriculum-review-lesson-review-and-materials-re.  Though you're right that those descriptions should be in the tag usage guidance.  The tags themselves didn't exist yet when the meta was written :)

Comment: I can do that tomorrow,or if someone wants +12 rep, they can adapt the text before I get to it.

Comment: @BenI. whoops. Got there first (Yes! Timezone sneak attack!)

Comment: But not for materials-review?

Comment: @BenI. Should I start a new topic challenge topic suggestion meta?

Answer (score 1):

To get the ball rolling:

[Lesson plan for teaching java graphics](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/2757/lesson-plan-for-teaching-java-graphics).

Is this the way to do it?

Comment: Yes!  First entrant :)

Comment: @BenI. let us hope that I won't be the last. Can events be extended? because 3 days does seem a small amount :P

Answer (score 1):

It became urgent to ask (because of what I wrote at the top of the question):

[The Order of Subjects in beginners Curriculum](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/2903/the-order-of-subjects-in-beginners-curriculum) - tagged: [curriculum-review](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/curriculum-review).