# Topic Challenge 1 Winner and Challenge 2 Voting!

Tags: discussion, topic-challenges

The winner of our first question challenge, [The Review Spew](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210/topic-challenge-01-the-review-spew), was [ItamarG3](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/users/150/itamarg3)'s question, [the Order of Subjects in Beginner's Curriculum](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/2903/the-order-of-subjects-in-beginners-curriculum). And the winning answer was [iFrame](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/users/1743/iframe) for [The order of subjects in beginner's curriculum](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/a/2906/27). Congratulations, ItamarG3 and iFrame!

It is also time to determine the next contest topic. Place your nominations, one subject or tag per answer, below, and upvote the ones that seem interesting.  (Especially useful are contests that you might personally be able to enter into, as the goal is to encourage good content on the site!)

### UPDATE

The second Topic Challenge has been announced: [Topic Challenge #02: Being Selfish](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/q/275/58?cb=1).

Answer (score 4):

Name: The <strike>selfless</strike> selfish challenge

The challenge: tagged with [self-learning](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-learning)

Comment: Wouldn't that be the *selfish* challenge? ;-)

Comment: @BenI. I don't know, perhaps ;) I thought I'd give it a more positive name; up to you if you want to change it.

Comment: I loved the idea

Comment: How about the selfie challenge?

Comment: [meta-tag:status-completed]

Answer (score 1):

Name: The markings of a true challenge:

The challenge: tagged with any markup language ([html](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/html), [xml](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xml), [markup](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/markup), [markup-languages](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/markup-languages), [latex](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latex)) tag.

However, we should keep in mind that it's about teaching those languages\teaching their usage, and not the languages themselves (just reminding `;)`).