# Topic Challenge #02: Being Selfish

Tags: discussion, topic-challenges

*(I'd like to give a special thanks to ItamarG3 for his help writing up this challenge. Please give him a round of applause, everyone!)*

> *"In case of emergency, air masks will drop from the ceiling. If you are traveling with someone who needs assistance, please put on your own mask before helping others."*

So, the time has come for us to start another [Topic Challenge](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207/topic-challenges). There are a few changes this time around!

#### Time frame

8/12, 0:00 $\rightarrow$ 23:59, 8/21 (times in UTC).

#### Challenge: Topic Tag

This challenge is for the [self-learning](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-learning) tag. During the final judging (probably a day or two after the end of the specified time frame), each question entered will be given points (these won't be visible to anyone except for the judges). The question with the highest number of points is the winner. (Points and post score and not necessarily the same).

#### Entering the challenge

For a question to be entered, three conditions must be met:

1. It **must** be posted *within* the specified time frame. (which means that posting it before or after doesn't get it entered).
2. It **has** to be tagged with [self-learning](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-learning) (I think this is fairly reasonable).
3. You **have** to add an answer to this meta post.*The answer is your entry ticket, and should follow the format outlined at the end of this post*.

And a fourth option to make it visible from the question page: You can add a comment to your question: `*This question has been entered into [The Being Selfish challenge question contest](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275/topic-challenge-02-being-selfish).*`

#### Further notes

Edits made after the end of the specified time frame and the final judging may disqualify the question.

#### Question judging

1. 10 points per upvote on the question itself.
2. 3 points per answer that is created, and 1 points per upvote on any answer.  *So, if an answer is created that gets 3 upvotes, it will be worth 6 points to a question’s overall score).  Self-answers will not earn the question points, but may still gain upvote points in this category*. (which means that interesting questions which attract answers rank higher than those who bring relatively few answers)
3. Each judge may award up to 35 points based on *how much of an exemplar the question is for the tag*, and up to 5 additional points for *any other considerations* (such as great writing, etc).

#### Structure of submission answers (For when you add an answer to this post)

---

The format of answers to this post should be like this:

`## Question link`<sup>1</sup>
`<br>`
`tags:` `[tag:self-learning]`,... (here you write the tags your question has)

#### If you win

The winner will be announced when the judging period ends. 
The winner of the contest gets declared Ruler of the Tag and Generally All-Around Cool Person! If enough people enter the contest, SE may also add to this prize a Stack Exchange t-shirt! So get asking, and you might get some Stack Exchange Swag.

#### Good luck to everyone

> *“There comes a point in your life,
>
>   when you have to stop reading other people's questions
>
>   and write your own”*
>
> **- With Apologies to Albert Einstein**

---

<sup>**1** - right click on the question title from within the question, then `copy link address`</sup>

Comment: Please use international time format (), I was looking at this “8/12, 0:00 → 23:59, 8/21 (times in UTC).” for 15 seconds trying to work out if it had a date, so I could see if it was too late. Then I saw that it starts on 8th December (Strange, a long way in the future), and ends on 8th of diciannovember. Opps I must have read that wrong.

Comment: I had no idea about this until now. I assume this is same for others. Therefore can we publicise it more. It would be good if it appeared in my notifications.

Comment: @richard Would --8-12 truly be easier to understand than 8/12?  As to publicity, it was in the upper right corner of every site page you loaded for the entire duration of the contest. Unfortunately, SE doesn't give us the ability to ping site users about events, so fixing a meta into that upper box on the right is the most intense advertising available to us within the site. We're  unsure of what we can do further, though open to more advertising ideas.

Comment: `--8-12` is not any format that I know of.
ISO 8601 says do it as `2017-08-12T00:00`. Not every one is from America: UK does date `12/08/2017` or shortened form `12/08`, I don't know about other local ways.

Comment: @richard Internation Time Format is not just one way of writing everything. `--8-12` is the [ISO 8701 standard](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) way of writing the date without the year. I'm not sure why the UK is reversed from ISO. Also, these dates were not written by an American ;-)

Comment: The good thing about standards is there are so many to choose from. The UK method is, pre-iso. If you treat each component as an atom, then it is little endian. So little endian, with big endian components. The US is big endian for month-day, but little endian for the year (scrambled). ISOs are simply big endian, there for they sort if treated as numbers or plain text (as long as one is consistent to use the same format each time).

Answer (score 1):

I'm told we have a contest thingy going on, so...

### [Strategies for self-learners to transition into working on larger projects](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/q/3228/732)

tags: [self-learning](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-learning) [project](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/project)

Answer (score 1):

### [Attempting to prevent learning of poor techniques when self-teaching](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/3266/attempting-to-prevent-learning-of-poor-techniques-when-self-teaching)

tags: [self-learning](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-learning) [coding-style](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coding-style)